# Wrong number of template arguments for member of template struct (1 should be 3)

Tags: c++, templates

I have a struct like so

```
namespace Binning_ {   
    template <typename data_type, uint32_t number_of_bins, bool uses_integrals>
    struct Binner {
        void setup();
    /* ... */
```

Now I want to implement it. Of course I would expect that I have to implement it somehow like

```
namespace Binning_ {  
    template <typename data_type, uint32_t number_of_bins, bool uses_integrals>
    void Binner<typename data_type, uint32_t number_of_bins, bool uses_integrals>::setup() { 
        /* ... */
    }
```

The compiler keeps telling me about wrong number of template arguments.

```
/home/udo/dev/libraries/dcf77/dcf77.cpp:305:81: error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 3)
     void Binner<typename data_type, uint32_t number_of_bins, bool uses_integrals>::setup() {
                                                                                 ^
/home/udo/dev/libraries/dcf77/dcf77.cpp:259:12: error: provided for 'template<class data_type, long unsigned int number_of_bins, bool uses_integrals> struct Binning_::Binner'
     struct Binner {
            ^
```

However I do not get it. Of course I have to pass 3 template arguments. But why does the compiler count only 1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must not repeat the types in the argument list for `Binner`:

```
template <typename data_type, uint32_t number_of_bins, bool uses_integrals>
  void Binner<data_type, number_of_bins, uses_integrals>::setup() { 
        /* ... */
}
```

should work.